# Why this query is running so slow?

Tags: sql-server, database, query-optimization

This query runs very fast (<100 msec):

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent2].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId]
    ,[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    ,[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status]
FROM [dbo].[SplittedSms] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Sms] AS [Extent2]
    ON [Extent1].[SmsId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent2].[CompanyId] = 4563 
    AND ([Extent1].[NotifiedToClient] IS NULL)
```

If I add just a time filter, it takes too long (22 seconds!):

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Extent2].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId]
    ,[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id]
    ,[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status]
FROM [dbo].[SplittedSms] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Sms] AS [Extent2]
    ON [Extent1].[SmsId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE [Extent2].Time > '2015-04-10'
    AND [Extent2].[CompanyId] = 4563 
    AND ([Extent1].[NotifiedToClient] IS NULL)
```

I tried adding an index on the `[Time]` column of the `Sms` table, but the optimizer seems not using the index. Tried using `With (index (Ix_Sms_Time))`; but to my surprise, it takes even more time (29 seconds!).

Here is the actual execution plan:
[image]

The execution plan is same for both queries. Tables mentioned here have 5M to 8M rows (indices are < 1% fragmented and stats are updated). I am using MS SQL Server 2008R2 on a 16core 32GB memory Windows 2008 R2 machine)

Comment: Try adding ORDER BY ASC or DESC TIME column and check. It should run faster.

Comment: First, without `ORDER BY`, the rows returned by the `TOP` query is not deterministic.  The best practice is to specify `ORDER BY` with `TOP`. To improve performance of the second query, try a composite nonclustered index on CompanyID and Time.  That will avoid touching the rows <= '2015-04-10'.

Comment: Tried `Order By [Time]`; worse, 29 seconds!

Comment: Can you post the create tables scripts? Together with the index definition

Comment: can you please post actual execution plan somewhere so we and access it and see the actual matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there was no index on the foreign key column (`SmsId`) on the `SplittedSms` table. I made one and it seems the second query is almost as fast as the first one now.

The execution plan now:

[image]

Thanks everyone for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help when you force the time filter to kick in only after the client filter has run?

FI like in this example:

```
;WITH ClientData AS (   
    SELECT 
         [E2].[CompanyId]
        ,[E2].[Time]
        ,[E1].[Id]
        ,[E1].[Status]
    FROM [dbo].[SplittedSms] AS [E1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Sms] AS [E2]
        ON [E1].[SmsId] = [E2].[Id]
    WHERE  [E2].[CompanyId] = 4563 
      AND ([E1].[NotifiedToClient] IS NULL)
)
SELECT TOP 10
     [CompanyId]    
    ,[Id]
    ,[Status]
FROM ClientData
WHERE [Time] > '2015-04-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on `Sms` with the following `Index Key Columns` (in this order):

1. CompanyID
2. Time

You may or may not need to add `Id` as an `Included Column`.

Answer (score 0):

What datatype is your Time column?
If it's datetime, try converting your '2015-04-10' into equivalent data-type, so that it can use the index.

```
Declare @test datetime
Set @test='2015-04-10'
```

Then modify your condition:

```
[Extent2].Time > @test
```

The sql server implicitly casts to matching data-type if there is a data-type mismatch. And any function or cast operation prevent using indexes.

Comment: Changing the date into a variable will cause optimizer to optimize the clause for unknown value (if it's not a stored procedure), and in case of datetime fields and the date being close to current day it might make the situation worse. Having the datetime in correct format, e.g. '20150410' should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same track with @JonTirjan, the index with just Time results into a lot of key lookups, so you should try at least following:

```
create index xxx on Sms (Time, CompanyId) include (Id)
```

or

```
create index xxx on Sms (CompanyId, Time) include (Id)
```

If Id is your clustered index, then it's not needed in include clause. If significant part of your data belongs to CompanyID 4563, it might be ok to have it as include column too.

The percentages you see in actual plan are just estimates based on the row count assumptions, so those are sometimes totally wrong. Looking at actual number of rows / executions + statistics IO output should give you idea what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind:

1. By adding an extra restriction it will be 'harder' for the database to find the first 10 items that match your restrictions. Finding the first 10 rows from let's say 10.000 items (from a total of 1 milion) is a easier then finding the first 10 rows from maybe 100 items (from a total of 1 milion).
2. The index is not being used probably because the index is created on a datetime column, which is not very efficient if you are also storing the time in them. You might want to create a clustered index on the [time] column (but then you would have to remove the clustered index which is now on the [CompanyId] column or you could create a computed column which stores the date-part of the [time] column, create an index on this computed column and filter on this column.